# Integral $\int^{x=\frac{\pi}{4}}_{x=0} \int^{y= \cos{x}}_{y=\sin{x}} dydx$

Tags: definite-integrals

$$\int^{x=\frac{\pi}{4}}_{x=0} \int^{y= \cos{x}}_{y=\sin{x}} dydx$$

I got the answer $\sqrt{2} - 1 $ but my tutor got $8$? I assumed that I am starting with integrating $1 dydx$, that is how I got my answer.

Is my answer wrong?

Comment: Your answer seems correct.

Comment: show how to get that answer, what is important is not just a result at the end but the way to get it, a wrong answer with a correct way is way better than a correct answer done the wrong way.

Comment: Your tutor is wrong. The answer is definitely $\sqrt{2}-1$.

Comment: Like I said I started with 1dydx then pretty simple integrated f(x,y) = y using cosx-sinx then so on, but I had no idea how my tutor got 8!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So we have:
$$ I = \int_{x = 0}^{x = \frac{\pi}{4}} \!\!\!\int_{y = \sin{x}}^{y = \cos{x}} \!\!dydx  = \int_{x = 0}^{x = \frac{\pi}{4}}\!\! \big(\cos{x} - \sin{x}\big)  dx $$

The area bounded between cosine and sine between $0$ and $\frac{\pi}{4}$.

Hence:

$$
I =\big( \sin{x} + \cos{x} \big)_{x = 0}^{x=\frac{\pi}{4}} = \left(\sin{\frac{\pi}{4}} + \cos{\frac{\pi}{4}}\right) - \big(\sin{0} + \cos{0}) \big)  = \frac{\sqrt2}2+\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}- 1 = \sqrt{2} - 1
$$

Your answer is correct!

Comment: That's exactly what I got!! Amazing, thanks!